# Laravel how to clear cache of concrete storage?

Tags: laravel, caching, storage, laravel-artisan

So, sometimes when you use few cache drivers there is need to purge only one of them.

Cases:

- You have critical data in main cache pull
- You do not see changes after purged main storage with **cache:clear**

Answer (score 0):

Solution is:

```
php artisan cache:flush storage-name
```